# RC522 not recognized as NFC-reader

Tags: nfc

I've installed the RC522 module on my Raspberry Pi 3B according to this guide:
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/
Reading and writing with the python scripts works, but according to [this project I'm trying to make](https://github.com/Esamanoaz/NFC-Spotify-Casting) I have to define a device path as a constant. I can't see my RC522 using `lsusb` or `nfc-device-scan`, but as I said earlier, the device is working perfectly when executing the scripts.
What should i do?

Comment: You said, the following: "***I can't see my RC522 using lsusb or nfc-device-scan***, ...". Can you show us the commands you are suing, and the exact error messages you got?

Comment: I can't see `lsusb` or `nfc-device-scan` in your tutorial, why do you expect these commands to work?